# Show popup in access denied page

Tags: users, javascript

I want to show a popup for access denied page. Is there any module available for this? I know I can create a custom module for this but I want to know if there is any module available for this.

Comment: You mean on link click instead of actual content? Or when user enters URL directly? Ad do you want shadowbox-style popup, js alert window or new page in a oldschool popup window? Last one is pretty bad idea due to popup blockers.

Comment: Are you using d7 or D6?

Answer (score 1):

[Popup module](http://drupal.org/project/popup) allow you to display the access denied page in popup box.

> The popup suite allows builders to popup tooltip-like text, nodes,
>   blocks, menus, forms, views and php-generated content.

or

[Better Messages](http://drupal.org/project/better_messages) intends to let you control where and how you want to see your Drupal messages! Combine different animations and override

> Enable or disable popup messages at specific pages.