# Show access denied page as a modal form

Tags: users, javascript, forms

How do I show login redirect page as a modal form or dialog popup? I'd like to keep my site consistent since I'm using Modal Forms for login and register pages.

I'm not trying to display a popup showing an "Access Denied" error.

(edited for clarity)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show popup in access denied page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74285/show-popup-in-access-denied-page)

Comment: No, that one was about "Access denied" as a popup. I need to show a login form as a popup instead when access is denied.

Comment: Both the questions are about showing a popup when the "Access denied" error is being shown by Drupal. The difference is rather between asking about a specific module and no specific module. Still, if the Logintoboggan module requires another module to achieve the goal, then the questions are duplicates.

Comment: Just to make things clear: For Drupal, the "Access denied" page shown when the user is not logged-in is the same "Access denied" page shown when the user doesn't have the necessary user permissions to access a page.

Comment: I've spent a few hours testing out the Popup module and I don't think it's what I need. I think there is a misunderstanding because the possible duplicate address the problem of showing a popup of the ERROR message but I need a popup of the LOGIN form. If you have not misunderstood me then I've not been able to figure out how to get it to work and I appreciate your advice on how to proceed. I am open to any solutions that are available, be it simply using Logintoboggan or having another module. Thanks!